# What is the "parameter unpacking" error in pylint 1.4?

Tags: python, pylint

I have this piece of python code:

```
d = {"a": {}}
d["a"] = sorted(d["a"].iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v,): len(v.get('b')), reverse=True)
```

When I run this through pylint 1.4, I receive the warning:
 "E:  3,48: Parameter unpacking specified (parameter-unpacking)"

What does this error mean, and does it actually indicate something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating through a dictionary-iteritems object (which is done by calling its `.next()` method) yields 2-tuples. Your lambda function is taking two parameters, but the 2-tuple yielded by the dict-iteritems object is a single object.

You can fix this by just indexing into the tuple instead:

`d["a"] = sorted(d["a"].iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(x[1].get('b')), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 3):

Your lambda specifies that it is to receive a single parameter: a tuple, which is to be unpacked into the two variables `k` and `v`. If this is what you meant to do, then it's fine. I believe this is not supported in Python 3, which is probably why `pylint` is warning you about it.

Comment: Yes, this disappeared with [Pep 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) for reference